# Yeast starter left out of refrigerator, is it OK?

Tags: yeast

I created a yeast starter from some yeast from my primary fermenter and some DME following standard steps and the fermentation looked great.  However, I went on vacation and forgot to put my yeast after it was done w/fermentation in the refrigerator.

Is the yeast still good to use if I make another starter wort and add this yeast to it, or should I throw it out?  I have not touched it since it finished, so it is still sitting in a growler with a airlock and looks fine.

Comment: How long was it sitting out?

Comment: The yeast settled to the bottom about a week and a half ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you were careful and didn't introduce too much other yeasts you should be able to culture them again from the yeast in the growler. The biggest potential issue would be that the yeast are stressed from being out at RT with no nutrients. So what you can do is start a new starter. Then transfer cells from this culture and that should start a new starter culture with happier yeast. Beyond that as long as you can get a starter going with the yeast, which most likely shouldn't be a problem, then you are going to be fine.